# Repair blocks in android ARMv7

Tags: file-system, system, system-error

Hi would check the `badblocks` in my android with the `badblocks` tool, but I cant found the binary for my:

**armv7** with mt6582 - lollipop 5.1, and TWRP 3.0.1.

- How could compile or get it (the badblocks for execute from /sbin/)?

Note: I want not use e2fsck neither fsck.... I would like check it through of **badblocks**

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a Linux Desktop (Debian, Ubuntu, Suse) edition and install it on your PC
2. Get ARM (el, hf) compiler and binutils etc-
3. Get Android NDK and SDK (Large files...)
4. Get the kernel source for your smartphone/tablet too
5. Get badblock source files for linux, and cross compile it
6. BTW the smartphone should be rooted and be aware about the using (!) of badblocks...

Or find a developer here or at https://forum.xda-developers.com who has already compiled it

Comment: Thanks dude, I've downloaded the SDK and SDK, could be it my source https://github.com/mmeeks/ext2tools/blob/master/ext2fs/badblocks.c ?... I dont understant.. can you guide me to compile it?

Comment: Yep, it that file Did you get all other stuff? Android NDK is the most important  Please follow everything on the sites for com(google, xda-developers). It is too complex, to descirbe everything here. (DL the Kernel for your Device too)

Comment: Which device you own? Which partition of your device you want to use on badblocks? (If you use badblocks, maybe it will lock the partition and therefore the device)

Comment: I have mmblk0 (8gb) > with 9 partitions... But I dont know about of port the badblocks for armv7 of my device.... My device is azumi a50c+ (mtk 6582)